# Reformat label / preserve order of Multi-factor facets in ggplot2::facet_wrap() based on factor level

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I wish to facet a graph based on two factors, rename the facets using a combination of the two facet factor values, but preserve the order of the facets based on the levels in the original factors.

The data looks something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(100)

tmp.d <- data.frame(
  sector = factor(rep(c("B","A"),c(6,3)), levels = c("B","A")),
  subsector = factor(rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3), levels = c("c","b","a")),
  year = factor(rep(2020:2022,3)),
  value = sample(8:15,9, replace = TRUE)
)

#> tmp.d
#  sector subsector year value
#1      B         a 2020     9
#2      B         a 2021    14
#3      B         a 2022    13
#4      B         b 2020    15
#5      B         b 2021    10
#6      B         b 2022     8
#7      A         c 2020     9
#8      A         c 2021    13
#9      A         c 2022    11
```

Which is plotted and faceted by sector and subsector...

```
ggplot(tmp.d, aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap(facets = list("sector","subsector"))
```

...and looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the facets keep the order set by the factor levels of "sector" and "subsector." This is desirable.

However, instead of listing the sector and sub sector on separate lines, I want the facet labels to read "[sector]: [subsector]" as in "B: b".

**Attempt 1:**

Adding a helper column to tmp.d, containing the facet labels.

```
tmp.d <- tmp.d %>% mutate(label = factor(paste0(sector, ": ", subsector)))

ggplot(tmp.d, aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap(facets = list("label"))
```

Which yields:

[image]

Here, the facet labels are correct, but I've lost the order from the sector/subsector factor levels.

**Attempt 2:**

I think the answer may lay in a custom `as_labeller` function or perhaps even changing setting for an existing labeller like `label_value` which has a `multi_line = [bool]` attribute that controls whether the facet values appear on a single line or mulitple lines.  Other versions of the `label_` family have another attribute `sep =`  which I beleive controls how the values are seperated in on the same line. Presumably, the combination of `...multi_line = FALSE, sep = ": "...` might format the label and preserve the desired order.

The labeller is applied in the call to `facet_wrap()`.

```
ggplot(tmp.d, aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap(facets = list("sector","subsector"), labeller = [the labeller function])
```

Setting the labeller to an existing labeller function without changing default settings (see below) yields the same output as my original attempt above.

```
...
facet_wrap(facets = list("sector","subsector"), labeller = label_value)
...
```

Attempting to change the attribute values for label_value like so...

```
...
facet_wrap(facets = list("sector","subsector"), labeller = label_value(multi_line = FALSE))
...
```

... does not work because the `label_value` function requires a `label` value that I do not know how to provide. Passing the facet factors as names or as character strings (either as a list or vector) does not appear to work. The examples I found in the documentation or elsewhere use `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap`, and the `labels` is provided as a formula like `~sector+subsector` which I assume is treated like a grid/matrix where sectors are columns and subsectors are rows.  In my case, most (but not necessarily all) combinations of sector/subsector will be unique (i.e., Sectors A and B do not share subsectors).

**Question Summary**

Is there a simple way to acheive my objectives (restated for convenience):

- facet on two factor variables (facet_wrap, not facet_grid)
- preserve facet order based on factor levels
- reformat the facet label to a single line with sector and subsector sepearted by a colon

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was a lot trickier than I expected... One solution would be to combine them into a different field:

```r
tmp.d |> 
  arrange(sector, subsector) |>          # arrange by factor levels
  mutate(
    facet = 
      paste0(sector, ": ", subsector) |>    
      fct_inorder(ordered = TRUE)        # use that order for the new field
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap(facets = ~facet)            # here
```

This also works if a ", " is acceptable:

```r
ggplot(tmp.d, aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap(
    facets = sector~subsector, 
    labeller = 
      labeller(                  # here
        sector = label_value,    #
        subsector = label_value, #
        .multi_line = FALSE      #
      )
  )
```

A similar thing can be done with `purrr::partial()` which substitutes out defaults but again you get a comma. I think it would be worth creating an issue on their github page to add a `sep` argument to the `label_*()` functions

```r
... +
  facet_wrap(
    facets = sector~subsector, 
    labeller = purrr::partial(label_value, multi_line = FALSE)
  )
```

Comment: Your second option is perfect for me (other than the "sep" issue) and also helped me understand the labeller function better beyond my specific question.   Your first option works great.

Comment: For future readers, I wanted to add that in @yake84's first solution, if tmp.d were created in the same pipeline using group_by to summarize variables (instead of implicitly like my example), you may have to ungroup before `mutate(facet = ...)`. At least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Meanwhile yake84 already finished the answer:
To automate just add `fct_inorder..` after using `arrange`:

```
tmp.d %>% 
  arrange(sector, subsector) %>% 
  mutate(my_label = paste(sector,subsector, sep=":") %>% 
           fct_inorder(ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap( ~ my_label)
```

**First answer:**
Just transform your label in attempt 1 to factor and define the levels:

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp.d %>% 
  mutate(my_label = paste(sector,subsector, sep=":")) %>% 
  mutate(my_label = factor(my_label, levels = c("B:b", "B:a", "A:c"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_path()+
  facet_wrap( ~ my_label)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on automating the order of the levels in your second mutate based on the existing factor levels for sector and subsector?  The actual data set may have many sector/subsector combinations and the sectors and subsectors may change, so manually defining the order like that may not be practical.

Comment: Sure. Please see my update!